# how to change directory using exec command from C program?

Tags: c, unix

I have to change working directory from my C program. For this I have used the following command:
    `execl("/bin/cd","cd","..",(char*)0);`
but this command  is not changing the directory?
     Is anything wrong in this command or is there any other way to change working directory from C program?

Answer (score 10):

To change the current directory you should use [`chdir`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/chdir):

```
int chdir(const char *path);
```

On success it returns 0.

You can't use execl for several reasons:

1. `cd` is typically a shell builtin command;
2. on most systems `/bin/cd` does not exists; on the very very few systems that have it, it changes the current directory and then spawns a child shell process;
3. the current directory is a process' property: if you change the current directory using `/bin/cd`, you'd lose the directory change as soon as the process terminates;
4. if you use a function from the `exec` family, the current process image is replaced with a new process image - you could use `system`, but wouldn't fix the previous 3 problems.

Comment: This does not answer the question. Some class assignments have strict rules where you need to use exec and not chdir.

Comment: Then some class assignment have strict rules that are mutually exclusive with the POSIX standard.

Answer (score 2):

What you are doing won't work because the [`exec`](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/exec.html) family of calls will actually *replace* your current program in the current process. In other words, you will have been terminated so that, when `cd` is finished, your *parent* process will once again take over.

If you want to change the working directory for the current process, use [`chdir`](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/chdir.html). If you want to change it on exit, you're out of luck because your program itself is running in a separate process from the parent that started it.

So, unless you have some form of communication with the parent, that's not going to work.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the [`chdir`](http://comsci.liu.edu/~murali/unix/chdir.htm) system call to change the working directory of the calling process.